# How to put the required parameters in link that accesses php?

Tags: php

www.example.com/login.php?Email=test@gmail.comAND?Password=something50

I have a mysql operation which requires 2 parameters(Email and Password)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID='".$email."'AND'".$pass."'";
```

so how do I put those parameters in the link above because it works when I have 1 parameter but than I don't know how to add the second one.

Comment: Using `&` sign.

Comment: with GET arrays; where are those?

Comment: You need to go back to basics here. Firstly, *never* send sensitive data over GET, i.e. as query string arguments. Secondly, your SQL is open to injection attacks, so look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: You should also look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `?Password=something50` gotta love plain text passwords over an (possible) HTTP protocol, huh?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - come on, he's new to this. Help him out rather than resort to sarcasm. It's easy to mock the inexperienced.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Where are you seeing sarcasm @Utkanos? Can you get that from plain text?

Comment: Be very careful when building a request like this because you're open to SQL Injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to fix your query string, the `?` starts the string and each additional argument is prefixed with `&`:

```
www.example.com/login.php?Email=test@gmail.com&Password=something50
```

Now all of the variables will be available in the `$_GET` array

```
$_GET['Email']; // is equal to "test@gmail.com"
$_GET['Password']; // is equal to "something50"
```

You should never concatenate variables in a SQL statement, you should use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. Here is a MySQLi example where you use the `$_GET` variable in one of your bound parameters:

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID = ?");
$sql->bind_param('s', $_GET['Email']); // here we use the $_GET variable
```

Since you should never store plain text passwords you should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding. Also, passing credentials in the query string is *easily* hackable and should not be done.